# DataTables.Net Buttons Not showing

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller, datatables

I have a simple MVC proj, using BootStrap4 and dataTables.Net. 
 [Link to DataTables.net](https://datatables.net) It makes an Ajax call after page loads to retrieve data for a table.  But as per the Docs I have gone through. I can not get the buttons to display on the page.  There are no errors and everything loads as expected only without the Buttons.

It appears to work correcty in Explorer, but not Chrome. 
I believe it has to do with the ajax call to retrieve the data but haven't figured it out yet.

The Call on the Layout page to Initialize CSS and JS:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/schit")
```

Heres the Bundles in the BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/schit").Include(
             "~/Scripts/DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"
            ,"~/Scripts/DataTables/extensions/Buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.js"
            , "~/Scripts/DataTables/extensions/Buttons/js/dataTables.html5.js"
            , "~/Scripts/DataTables/extensions/Buttons/js/buttons.print.js"
             , "~/Scripts/DataTables/extensions/Buttons/js/buttons.colVis.js"
             , "~/Scripts/DataTables/extensions/Buttons/js/buttons.flash.js"
       ));


        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"
                  , "~/Content/DataTables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"
                  , "~/Content/DataTables/extensions/Buttons/css/buttons.dataTables.css"
            ));



<table id="ListTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Center
        </th>
        <th>
            Account
        </th>
        <th>
            Ledger
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#ListTable').DataTable({

        ajax: '/Home/GetStuff',
        dataSrc: 'data',
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'copy',
                text: 'copy'
            },

            'excel',
            'csv',
            'pdf'
        ],
        columns: [
            { data: 'Center' },
            { data: 'Account' },
            { data: 'Ledger' }
        ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting to help save someone else some time...  I have to give credit to DataTables.net they have pretty good support but the documentation can be tricky.

After doing some more digging and with the guidence of the DataTables.Net Forum. Heres what I came up with.  I ended up using the DataTables.Net Downloader to Generate all the CSS and Js Files into 2 bundles files with all the features that I was trying to add.  So instead of DLing them individually It was just 2 files in the bundles.   [Heres the Downloader Link](https://www.datatables.net/download/)
Then the Bundles ended up like this.

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/DataTables").Include(
          "~/DataTables/dataTables.min.js"

            ));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/DataTables").Include(
            "~/DataTables/dataTables.min.css" 
        ))
```

Then on the Layout page or your HTML page where the tables are going to live.  include the scripts and content
Place Content in the Head.

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/DataTables")
```

Place the Script before the closing  tag

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/DataTables")
```

On the page my HTML was pretty much Unchanged. I did add the BootStrap CSS Classes for tables.

```
<table id="MyTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" style="width:100%">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>
        Center
    </th>
    <th>
        Account
    </th>
    <th>
        Ledger
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
```

In the Script Section for that page. 
Couple things here... the Documentation is kinda scattered but , there are a few different ways to set this up.  For example there 'May' be a Ajax section, and the buttons can either be declared directly or instantiated separately with the New constructor.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

      var table =  $('#MyTable').DataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: 'Ajax Call for data',
                dataSrc: 'data'
            },
            columns: [
        { data: 'Center' },
        { data: 'Account' },
        { data: 'Ledger' }
    ]
        });


        new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons( table, {
            buttons: [
                'copy', 'excel', 'pdf'
            ]
        });

        table.buttons( 0, null ).container().prependTo(
            table.table().container()
        );
    });
</script>
```